# Trigger GitLab CI/CD job with rules

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have this job:

```yaml
    .test:
      stage: test
      image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
      rules:
        - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED == "true"'
          when: never
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
        - changes:
          - "my-folder/**/*"
          - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
          when: never
  allow_failure: false
```

I extend this job like this:

```yaml
    linting_js:
      extends:
        - .test
      script:
        - yarn install
        - yarn run lint
```

I would like to perform this job *only* if we are in a merge request and only if there are no changes on files in the folder `my-folder` and in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

When I make a change in `my-folder`, the job is still running. Why?

---

I tried something else in my job like this :

```
.test:
  stage: test
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED == "true"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - ':!.gitlab-ci.yml'
        - ':!my-folder/**/*'
      when: always
  allow_failure: false
```

I extend this job in the same way as my initial post.

If I make a change in `.gitlab-ci.yml` or in a file from `my-folder/**/*`, the job is not running, so in this way it's ok.

But if I edit a file that is not in `my-folder` or if I don't edit the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, the pipeline doesn't start and gitlab stuck in pending for checking pipelines :

[image]

How can I run my job only in merge request and not when I edit the `.gitlab-ci.yml` or a file presents in `my-folder` ?

Comment: What's the point of the first rule?

Comment: I've added this rule because I need to make sure this job only runs as part of a merge_request, but it shouldn't run if there's a change in my-folder and .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: But the first rule matches for any merge_request, so the second can't be reached in that case - [_"Rules are evaluated in order until the first match."_](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-rules)

Comment: I made a change in my initial post.
I try this part of code in order to not run the job if there are changes in my-folder and .gitlab-ci.yml. But it does not work.

Comment: You've changed it but the second rule still isn't reached at all for merge requests; it's the exact same problem.